# How to combine duplicate rows in google sheets using query function

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula that should combine rows from another sheet containing the same cell data in column A:

```
 =QUERY(COMBINE!A:G, "select A,max(B),max(C),max(D),min(E),min(F), sum(G)  group by A")
```

However; this does not seem to be working as per the pic below.

[screen shot of sheet formula is on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWXIN.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

formula is fine. looks like those two cells are not identical (perhaps one of them contains extra spaces on the end) if cant be fixed manually try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({TRIM(COMBINE!A:A), COMBINE!B:G}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col2),max(Col3),max(Col4),min(Col5),min(Col6),sum(Col7)  
  group by Col1"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That did not work either.  It's baffling. When I use the 'UNIQUE'  function, it removes one of those entries. But then I do not know how to use 'UNIQUE' and still gather the information from the other columns.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using REGEXTRACT function and letter count. Very suspect work around but it's functioning now.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share you full function so that other users with similar questions can easily find the answer? Thanks !